# Manipulating Series in Dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a date column in a data frame that looks like this:

```
(Year-Month-Day)
2017-09-21
2018-11-25
```

I am trying to create a function that considers only the year, I have been trying the following.

```
df[df['DateColumn'].str[:3]=='2017']
```

But I am receiving this error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

How can I only consider the first four characters of the date in a function? Thanks.

Comment: It appears to be telling you that you can't access a datetime object with string methods. [Here is the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) with more reading about accessing pandas datetime values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
df['year'] = [d.year for d in df['DateColumn']]
```

This works only if the elements of the column are pandas.tslib.Timestamp. If not then :

```
df['DateColumn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateColumn'])
df['year'] = [d.year for d in df['DateColumn']]
```

**UPDATE:** Use this instead:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['DateColumn']).dt.year == 2017]
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['DateColumn']).dt.year` when you using pandas try no use for loops

Comment: Ok, I'll keep in mind.Thanks:)

Comment: I think this is similar with what I got that worked: df.loc[df.loc[:, 'DateColumn'].dt.year == 2017, :]

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dt-accessor

If you have a Series in a DateTime format, you should be able to use the dt accessor.

So you might be able to do something like this:

```
df[df.dt.year == 2017]
```

Comment: `df` is a dataframe, not a series. It will not have a `dt` accessor. Please test your code before posting an answer.

Comment: Oops my bad, the title says Series in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`df = pd.to_datetime(df.col).apply(lambda x: x.year)`

This converts `col` into datetime format, then extracts year from it to make it a series.